# Understanding Humphreys LIe algebras, page 32

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I have two questions.

First question is about Remark in page 32. Let $x, y, h$ be a standard basis of $\mathfrak sl(2, F).\,V_\lambda$ is a weight space. We have the following lemma :

> Lemma. If $v \in V_\lambda,$ then $x.v \in V_{\lambda+2}$ and $y.v \in V_{\lambda-2}.$

And here is the remark related to this lemma.

> Remark. The lemma implies that $x, y$ are represented by nilpotent endomorphisms of $V.$

Here's my opinion.

For any $v \in V, v \in V_\lambda$ for some $\lambda.$ Then, $x.v \in V_{\lambda+2} \Rightarrow x^2.v \in V_{\lambda+4} \Rightarrow ...\Rightarrow x^n.v \in V_{\lambda+2n}.$ Since $V$ is finite dimensional, $V_{\lambda+2n}=0$ for some $n.$ Hence $x$ is nilpotent. Nilpotency of $y$ can be shown similarly.

Am I right ?

Second question is about the paragraph right next to the proof of lemma in the same page 32.
It says that

> Thanks to formula (a), the nonzero $v_i$ are all linearly independent.

And again, here's what I thought.

Formula (a) is $h.v_i=(\lambda-2i)v_i.$ Suppose that $\sum c_iv_i=0.$ By (a), $0=h(0)=h(\sum c_iv_i)=\sum(\lambda-2i)c_iv_i.$
Again, $0=h(0)=h(\sum(\lambda-2i)c_iv_i)=\sum(\lambda-2i)^2c_iv_i.$ Repeating this process, we obtain

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 &\cdots& 1 \\
    \lambda-2 & \lambda-4 &\cdots& \lambda-2n \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\
    (\lambda-2)^{n-1} & (\lambda-4)^{n-1} & \cdots & (\lambda-2n)^{n-1} \\
    \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} c_1v_1\\ c_2v_2\\ \vdots \\ c_nv_n \end{pmatrix}=0
$$

Since the left matrix is invertible (indeed, it is Vandermonde matrix), we have $c_iv_i=0$ for each $i.$ Thus $c_i=0$ for all $i$ and hence $v_i$'s are linearly independent.

Am I correct ? If I'm wrong, could you give me some hint ?
Thanks for reading the long questions and thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in both cases. But the second assertion is a particular case of the general Linear Algebra fact that eigenvectors with distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.